Start vlock as a screensaver on console only debian
I am using a revived Chromebook as a secondary laptop. The eMMC is mostly fried, but I have a UEFI grub settup that boots Debian from an SD card. It is console only - no X11, etc.
I can get the screen to blank with setterm -blank 5 and I can lock with vlock -as. How do I combine the two? The end goal is to have the screen blank and lock after 5 minutes.
